# regex for Google script to extract hour and time

Tags: regex

How do I extract the hour and minute from a string containing full date using the regex?

```
text= "February 28, 2016 at 03:14PM";

hour= text.replace (/s /g , "");
min= text.replace (/s /g , "");
```

TYhe expected result (hour in 24 format) should be:

```
hour=15
min=14
```

Answer (score 0):

`(\d{2}):(\d{2})((P|A)M)`

So you expect two digits (and put it into a capturing group), colon, and two digits (and put it into a capturing group) and after that you make a capturing group, so you extract AM or PM separately. After that you have to compare, in a programming language you use, its value with `AM` or `PM` and add or not 12 to hours.

Here is a demo: https://regex101.com/r/rT7aG3/2

You did not specify a language, so I make an example in `R`:

```
library(stringi)
text= "February 28, 2016 at 03:14PM";
ret <- stri_match_all_regex(text, "(\\d{2}):(\\d{2})((P|A)M)")
hour = as.integer(ret[[1]][1,2])
minute = as.integer(ret[[1]][1,3])
if(ret[[1]][1,4] == "PM")
    hour <- hour + 12
```